# Using the same parameter in different functions

Tags: c++

So I was curious about something.  I have two functions, both work the way I want them to, and they are as follows:

```
//this function returns the absolute value of a number
int abs(int y) {
    if (y < 0) {
        return -1 * y;
    }
    return y;
}

//gives a random number, multiplied by x, in the range 1-y
int randomNum(int x, int y) {
    srand((int)time(0));
    return abs(x * rand() % y) + 1;
}
```

They both work, so their functionality is not the problem.  But if you'll notice, they both use a parameter called "int y."

My question is, despite the fact that these two functions work, is this bad practice that might screw me over in more complex programs?  Or does it not matter because the variables are local to their respective functions?

I mean, it's obviously no big deal if I change one of the "int y" parameters to something else, I'm just curious, is all.

Comment: Do you know about scope of a variable?

Comment: Each name that appears in a C++ program is only valid in some possibly discontiguous portion of the source code called its scope. 
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Comment: Offtopic: you should call `srand` only once in your program, not on each function call.

Comment: You do know there's such a thing as `std::abs` - right? There's no need to build your own.

Comment: It's ultimately opinion based. A function called fabs takes an argument, but what should be be called? Similarly a function called randomNum(). You can certainly argue that using "y" in both contexts is confusing. However sin(theta) and cos(theta) isn't confusing, quite the reverse - to use different names would be confusing as it would suggest different conventions.

Comment: it totally fine to do so until the programs are simple.some times it might create a problem but you will know by yourself when it not the right time to do so.

Comment: I have a basic beginner's understanding of scope, I'll take it upon myself to read the link posted by Jawad Le Wywadi, thanks.

I was not aware of std::abs, I'll keep that in mind.  I'm still working through tutorials and haven't gotten to headers or libraries yet.

As for srand, I've moved that to the top of the main function, right before the random values are called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever there is a variable inside braces `{ }`, it is local to the scope. Once out of the `braces` it simply dies.

Now the code that you are asking,

```
// y is declared in abs and is alive only in the abs
int abs(int y) {
    if (y < 0) {
        return -1 * y;
    }
    return y;
}

// the previous y dies here and is inaccessible.

// a new instance of y is created in randomNum and it's valid till the brace ends
int randomNum(int x, int y) {
    srand((int)time(0));
    return abs(x * rand() % y) + 1;
}
```

Now a little thing to try out as pointed out by `Jawad Le Wywadi`

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    ++a;
    {
        int a = 1;
        a = 42;
        cout << a;
    }
    cout << a;
}
```

Try it yourself and let us know what do you realize in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is okay for simple programs.

> However, you should name a variable using the same care with which you
>   name a first-born child.

*Robert C. Martin, Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship*

For instance, nobody prefers to read the declaration `int foo(int x, int y, int z, int xx, int bb, int cc .....)`

Comment: I assumed what Robert Martin says is the case, I just wanted to ask for clarification, thanks.